# strange mysql error

Tags: mysql

i have 2 queries:

```
UPDATE dws_photogallery_albums a 
SET a.photoscount=(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dws_photogallery_photos p 
    WHERE p.albumid=a.albumid)

UPDATE dws_photoportfolio_photos a 
SET a.photoscount=(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dws_photoportfolio_photos p 
    WHERE p.albumid=a.albumid)
```

first works ok, but second gives me error:

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause
```

Tables are identical (differs only by name).
what can it be?

UPD: Men, i'm so sorry, it's just my missprint, queries must be like that:

```
UPDATE dws_photogallery_albums a 
    SET a.photoscount=(
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dws_photogallery_photos p 
        WHERE p.albumid=a.albumid)

    UPDATE dws_photoportfolio_albums a 
    SET a.photoscount=(
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dws_photoportfolio_photos p 
        WHERE p.albumid=a.albumid)
```

And they both works ok for me.
Thanks for answers, need more coffee

Comment: I'm surprised that the first one is working.

Comment: well... after reading your comments i'm surprised too.
ok, i d't want to play with fate and rewrite both queries (even if first works)

Comment: The best way is with a JOIN though, as Devart's answer.

Comment: btw, it's screenshots of phpmyadmin of working query
http://gyazo.com/b049992d4bcab692576627820ae3f010

Comment: @Dmitry There are solutions. But let me ask you - why are you going to store COUNT into table? You can calculate it using simple query any time.

Comment: Yes, and the stored Count value will become outdated.

Comment: maybe my post update answers your question... I'ts just count of photos in album - i think it's better to store it in field and update when adding/deleting new photos, then recalculate it everytime it needed.

Comment: @Dmitry: If there is a performance problem with counting every time you need it, yes, that's a valid reason to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means, that you can't update the table you are reading from. Aliases won't solve the problem. It could lead to inconsistencies. You have to work with temporary tables or in your case with variables.

Answer (score 2):

you are updating same table that you use in nested select.

you can't do this:

```
update table X
where  ... ( Select ... from X )
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not strange You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause.

Notice that you are having the same table for update and select in second query

Answer (score 2):

Try this query -

```
UPDATE
  dws_photoportfolio_photos a
  JOIN (
    SELECT albumid, COUNT(*) cnt FROM dws_photoportfolio_photos GROUP BY albumid
  ) p
  ON p.albumid = a.albumid
SET a.photoscount = p.cnt;
```